# How can i get directed tree from graph?

Tags: python, graph, tree, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(3,5)
G.add_edge(4,6)
G.add_edge(1,6)
G.add_edge(2,6)
G.add_edge(7,8)
G.add_edge(9,8)
mst=nx.prim_mst(G)# a generator of MST edges
```

I have got a tree. How can i get directed tree with root at 4?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the directed tree of breadth-first-search from node 4:

```
tree = nx.bfs_tree(G, 4)
```

[image]

---

To get the directed tree of depfth-first search from node 4:

```
tree = nx.dfs_tree(G, 4)
```

[image]

---

The graphs were generated this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(3,5)
G.add_edge(4,6)
G.add_edge(1,6)
G.add_edge(2,6)
G.add_edge(7,8)
G.add_edge(9,8)

tree = nx.bfs_tree(G, 4)
nx.draw(tree)
plt.savefig('/tmp/bfs_image.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be that @kalombo wants an oriented tree from the MST of G with root at node 4.  In that case you will need to build the graph of the MST first.  e.g.

```
T = nx.bfs_tree(nx.Graph(nx.prim_mst_edges(G)),4)
```